# Whenever I run a python file using vscode my terminal is black and I cant see anything on it

Tags: visual-studio-code

New to using vscode and programming. I've been learning in python and have been using vscode as my ide. Whenever I run a python file using the run button in vscode it takes me to the terminal.

The terminal shows up as a black screen with no writing on it. When I click on it i see my cursor and that's it.

[image]

Comment: what code are you running? it may not be relevant, but given that it is apparently just 8 lines it is easy enough for us to understand it. You can edit your question to post it in there.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.